# Create a Time class - OOP in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, datetime, reinventing-the-wheel, homework

## Create a `Time` class.

[Time is on my side](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIE2GAqnFGw)

### Specification

- Basic attributes: hour, minute, second and day (default is 0), + getters, + setters (using a decorator)
- If you try to initialize an incorrect value of seconds or minutes, i.e. greater than or equal to 60, raise an exception from your own `WrongSeconds` or `WrongMinutes` class

Add the following operators:

- `+`: works as follows - adds hours to hours, minutes to minutes, and so on, e.g. 2
  h 30 m 4 s + 6 h 35 m 50 s = 9 h 5 m 54 s (we also return an instance of the Time class), if we exceed 24 h, the day should be 1
- <: Compare first day, hours, then minutes, seconds. Return True / False, e.g.
  2 h 40 m 30 s d 0 < 1 h 59 m 30 s d 0 → False, 2 h 40 m 30 s d -1 < 1 h 59 m 30 s d 0 → True
- `__str__`: `Time` should be displayed as: "20:05:25, day without any changes" (when day = 1, -1 : next / previous day)

Add the function `zone`, which for a given instance of the `Time` class returns the appropriate time in another time zone. The argument of the function is the city for which we find the time: Warsaw, London, New York, Tokyo, Syndey, Moscow, Los Angeles. We assume that the default time is GMT.

- PEP8
- DOC
- tests

And here is the code!

```
class WrongSeconds(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Wrong amount of seconds passed (greater or equal 60)"
    
class WrongMinutes(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Wrong amount of minutes passed (greater or equal 60)"

    
    
class Time:
    TIME_ZONES = { "Warsaw": 2,
                   "London": 1,
                   "Tokio": 9,
                   "Sydney": 10,
                   "Moscow": 3,
                   "Los angeles": -7 }
    
    def __init__(self, d = 0, h = 0, m = 0, s = 0):
        self.days = d
        self.hours = h
        self.minutes = m
        self.seconds = s
        
    @property    
    def days(self):
        return self._d
    
    @days.setter
    def days(self, val):
        self._d = val
        
    @property    
    def hours(self):
        return self._h
    
    @hours.setter
    def hours(self, val):
        if val < 0:
            self.days += val//60
            val = 24 - abs(val)%24
        elif val >= 24:
            self.days += val//24
            val %= 24
        self._h = val
        
    @property    
    def minutes(self):
        return self._m
    
    @minutes.setter
    def minutes(self, val):
        if "_m" not in self.__dict__ and  val >= 60:
            raise WrongMinutes
        if val < 0:
            self.hours += val//60
            val = 60 - abs(val)%60
        elif val >= 60:
            self.hours += val//60
            val %= 60
        self._m = val
        
    @property    
    def seconds(self):
        return self._s
    
    @seconds.setter
    def seconds(self, val):
        if "_s" not in self.__dict__ and  val >= 60:
            raise WrongSeconds
        if val < 0:
            self.minutes += val//60
            val = 60 - abs(val)%60
        elif val >= 60:
            self.minutes += val//60
            val %= 60
        self._s = val
        
    def strefa(self, city):
        if city.capitalize() not in self.TIME_ZONES: raise ValueError(f"City {city} not in time zone database")
        
        result_time = self.__class__( self.days, self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds)
        result_time.hours += self.TIME_ZONES[city.capitalize()]
        
        return str(result_time)
        
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, self.__class__), f"Cannot add {type(other)} to a time object"
        result = self.__class__()
        
        result.seconds += self.seconds + other.seconds
        result.minutes += self.minutes + other.minutes
        result.hours   += self.hours   + other.hours
        result.days    += self.days    + other.days
        
        return result 
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, self.__class__), f"Cannot compare {type(other)} with a time object"
        
        if self.days < other.days: return True
        elif self.hours < other.hours: return True
        elif self.minutes < other.minutes: return True
        elif self.seconds < other.seconds: return True
        
        return False
        
    def __str__(self):
        s = f"{self.hours}:{self.minutes:02}:{self.seconds:02}"
                
        if self.days == 0 :
            return s + ", day without any changes"
        
        elif self.days == 1 :
            return s + ", the next day"
        
        elif self.days == -1 :
            return s + ", previous day"
        
        return s + f", day: {self.days}"
        
        
        
        
#  --- TEST CASES ---
try:
    time = Time(m = 60)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.__class__, e, "\n")
    
time = Time(d = 0, h = 23, m = 59, s = 59)
print(time)

time.seconds += 1
print(time, "\n")

time1 = Time(h = 3, m = 2, s = 1)
time2 = Time(h = 6, m = 5, s = 4)
print(time1 + time2, "\n")

print(time1 < time2 )
print(time2 < time1, "\n")

time_gmt = Time(h = 2, m = 0, s = 0)
print(time_gmt.strefa("London")) 
print(time_gmt.strefa("Sydney")) 
print(time_gmt.strefa("Los Angeles")) 
print("------------------------------------")
print("Comparisons")

t1 = Time(h = 14, m = 4, s = 35)
t2 =  Time(h = 8, m = 50, s = 25)

print(t1 + t2)
print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t1 < t2)
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.WrongMinutes'> Wrong amount of minutes passed (greater or equal 60) 

23:59:59, day without any changes
0:00:00, the next day 

9:07:05, day without any changes 

True
False 

3:00:00, day without any changes
12:00:00, day without any changes
19:00:00, previous day
------------------------------------
Comparisons
22:55:00, day without any changes
14:04:35, day without any changes
8:50:25, day without any changes
True
```

And here is my question, how to get a better solution? Maybe shorter? Maybe get rid of some operations, terms?

Comment: If you can't represent the 61st second of a minute, what's supposed to happen when there's a leap second??

Comment: um raise a wrongseconds/wrongminutes error i guess

Comment: That's fine - the code just pretends leap seconds don't exist.  I'm poking fun a little, but also pointing out that real date-time code has a lot of awkward real-world stuff to deal with, so better using the libraries than writing your own for actual use.

Comment: Well you know, sometimes (because its a task for school) I also don't see any sense in creating such complicated and thus simple things, but yeah, here we are! :D

Comment: One comment is, whenever you are implementing either of the comparison operators, you need to make sure you always implement them all. This would be, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==` and `!=`. Otherwise, the whoever used your `Time` class might run into trouble during comparisons without noticing.

Comment: Also worth noting that it's probably best to raise a `TypeError` in such methods, rather than using `assert`. `assert` is basically only used for tests/debugging, as you can run python in "all asserts silenced mode", which is sometimes done for optimisation purposes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273211/disable-assertions-in-python

Answer (score 1):

One small point:

When we inherit from `Exception`, we get its (actually, `BaseException`'s) `str()` implementation, so we don't need to provide `__str__()` if we initialise the base class `args` with the required string:

```
class WrongSeconds(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.args = [ "Wrong amount of seconds passed (greater or equal 60)" ]
```

---

In the addition, we have these new values:

```
    result.seconds += self.seconds + other.seconds
    result.minutes += self.minutes + other.minutes
    result.hours   += self.hours   + other.hours
    result.days    += self.days    + other.days
```

I don't see anything that handles overflow of any of these values (e.g. if hours > 24, we need to add a day and subtract 24 of the hours to get the values back into their allowed ranges).